# How to set eventOrder in fullcalendar-vue?

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

I have set up a calendar in my project with "fullcalendar-vue". Now for multiple events on the same day, events are listing in alphabetical order. I want to order events on the same day by a specific ID from the database.

"Fullcalender" has a property called 'eventOrder' for this, but I failed to figure out how to configure this is Vuejs.

```
<FullCalendar ref="fullCalendar"
            :plugins="calendarPlugins" 
            :events="calendarEvents"
            defaultView="dayGridMonth"
            nextDayThreshold="09:00:00"
            editable: false
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Events object:

```
events: [
      {
        title: "event one ",
        start: "2019-05-06",
        eventOrder: 1
      },
      {
        title: "event two ",
        start: "2019-05-06",
        eventOrder: 2
      },
    ]
```

Fullcalender component:

```
<FullCalendar ref="fullCalendar"
            :eventOrder="['eventOrder']"
            :plugins="calendarPlugins" 
            :events="calendarEvents"
            defaultView="dayGridMonth"
            editable: false
        />
```

Comment: Hi Vineeth, I have a FullCalendar Vue question as well. This is about adding Firebase to a FullCalendar Vue component. Would you be willing to take a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59382214/how-to-connect-firebase-to-fullcalendar-vue-component